# How to call the evaluateJavaScript function with an input parameter that is a JSON Array?

Tags: javascript, json, qt

In Qt, how would I call the `evaluatejavascript` function with an input parameter that is a JSON Array?

Comment: Please provide us some more information. Perhaps some code.

Comment: evaluateJavaScript("GetList('array')");

Comment: Assuming GetList is JavaScript function and array is JSON array what should be the calling convention??

Comment: JavaScript has a built in function to evaluate code called `eval`. So you would call `GetList` as `eval("GetList(array);")`. Note however that if you have access to the JavaScript scope then you can simply call `GetList(array);` directly.